# Using object name when AngularJS variable is defined in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Let's say we have an NameController in AngularJS. There you can define variables like this:

```
this.name = 'Joe';
```

Or:

```
$scope.name = 'Joe';
```

I always like to call all variables using the object notation:

```
<form ng-controller="NameController as nameCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="nameCtrl.name">
</form>
```

This only works when I use the 'this' notation in the controller. When I use the `$scope` I have to call 'name' without the `nameCtrl`. to make it work.

Of course I'm missing some very fundamental basics here, but after doing some research I'm still stuck. How can I preserve as much object naming as possible in my HTML code?

Comment: Just put name as a property of an object on the scope. You sbould be good. Example $scope.viewModel = {} and set it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only one method at a time, See more detail on this link
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

> Two different declaration styles are included below:
>
> - one binds methods and properties directly onto the controller using this: ng-controller="SettingsController1 as settings"
> - one injects $scope into the controller: ng-controller="SettingsController2"

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies! Shame on me that it was on top of this basic article, but I have a habit of inefficient speedreading.

Answer (score 0):

Angular js has a feature `ControllerAs`. This is what you are using now. You are just referencing your `nameCtrl` object to `NameController` object. And you are accesing the name value with the clone of the controller object. Imagine that `this` is only a pointer to `$scope`

Here is a nice technical introduction: [Angular Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

If you want to use objects everywhere, you can use `Angular Service` injected to your controller so you can easily call any object from your service in every controller.